# Get all table names set up in SessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there a way to retrieve the name of all tables that are managed by the `SessionFactory`? For instance, all the tables that were added via `AnnotationConfiguration.addAnnotatedClass(...))`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is howto getting one tableName with `getClassMetadata`

```
ClassMetadata cm = sessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(className);

AbstractEntityPersister aep = (AbstractEntityPersister) cm;
String tableName = aep.getTableName();
```

**[EDIT]** : you can find all by calling `getAllClassMetadata()` and find all table names like that

```
Map m = sessionFactory.GetAllClassMetadata();
/* iterate map*/
AbstractEntityPersister aep = m.get(/*key (className)*/) 
String tableName = aep.getTableName();
```

Comment: +1 use "getAllClassMetadata" method and you will get an array of getAllClassMetadata that you can iterate and collect all the table names

Comment: g should be small as well (in getClassMetadata method)

Comment: `getClassMetadata` and `getAllClassMetadata` are now deprecated

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JPA instead of direct dependency on hibernate., following code should help in getting all table names

```
private List<String> getAllTables() {
    List<String> tableNames = new ArrayList<>();
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = session.getSessionFactory();
    Map<String, ClassMetadata>  map = (Map<String, ClassMetadata>) sessionFactory.getAllClassMetadata();
    for(String entityName : map.keySet()){
        SessionFactoryImpl sfImpl = (SessionFactoryImpl) sessionFactory;
        String tableName = ((AbstractEntityPersister)sfImpl.getEntityPersister(entityName)).getTableName();
        tableNames.add(tableName);
    }
    return tableNames;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(className);
```

is deprecated. Use

```
    Metamodel metamodel = entityManager.getMetamodel();
    Set<EntityType<?>> entities = metamodel.getEntities();

    entities.forEach(e -> {
        System.out.println(e.getName());
    });
```

Your can also get `metamodel` from SessionFactory

Answer (score 1):

You can try using native sql queries.

```
session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM user_tables").list();
```

which gives list of tables owned by loggedin user or else you can use 'all_tables' or 'dba_tables' for all the tables for oracle database.If mysql db is used then replace the query with "SHOW TABLES"