# Get all join tables managed by the SessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate

This is a continuation of a question I posed [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813122/get-all-table-names-set-up-in-sessionfactory).

Currently when I get all tables managed by the SessionFactory using the technique in the solution to my previous post, it (as expected) does not include any join tables.  Is there an easy way to retrieve all join tables known to the SessionFactory or would I have to go through all Entity classes and reflectively find all @JoinTable annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [howto](http://byprogrammerforprogrammer.com/2009/10/hibernate-get-table-name-from-mapped-class/)

```
ClassMetadata cm = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(className);

if (Joinable.class.isInstance(cm)) ...
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't that just tell you whether an Entity class happens to join to another Entity class? but not necessarily with the name of the Join table is?

Comment: I've used part of the solution above by calling getAllClassMetaData() which gives you a Map.  The keySet() of this Map returns you a Set<String> which you can iterate and use Class.forName(String) and then just use reflection to find the names of the Join Tables.