# Get all Tables in a Db using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there a way to retrieve the name of all tables in the database using hibernate?
I executed the query `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES` in an oracle Db and it works just fine. 
But when it comes to DB2, it wont.

Comment: Link:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3584161/259889 

This helped I believe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813122/get-all-table-names-set-up-in-sessionfactory

Comment: If entities are used, instead of native queries, Is there any approach to get the table names irrespective of the database?

Comment: Use the JDBC API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
List<Object> list = session.createQuery("from java.lang.Object").list();
```

This will return all persistent entities (thanks to HQL implicit polymorphism), and this is db independent. Note that it will exclude tables with no records.

If you need all tables, including the empty ones, you can use native sql query

```
List<Object[]> list = session.createSQLQuery("select * from sysibm.systables").list();
```

The drawback for the native query is that it is specific for each database, for example, on Oracle the query is "select * from user_tables".